# Problem with Curve Modifier in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, modifiers, animation-nodes

I instance a curve on the vertexes of a circle mesh. I create a plane with a curve modifier and instance it. I loop through the curve and plane instances, assigning each plane a curve to the **modifiers["Curve"].object** attribute.

Using the normals of my circle mesh, I scale the locations of the planes planes. The resulting motions of the planes are not identical, because they all have the same deformation axis set for the curve modifier (x).

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=198Vkm07FSHbKfF9m9cOaZFv-yLtLnw8F) is the blend file.

Is there a way to get get the planes to deform uniformly? 
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the blende file. Also, are we to assume that you mean that you'd like the planes to hold the shape of the path as it travels or simply travel along the path from the center?

Comment: Using Blender with AN is sometimes not the best idea due to the limitations that this impose. I recommend you use Animation Nodes for everything. Would you like to see a solution with pure AN?

Comment: If there is a way to have deformations similar to the curve modifier just with animation nodes I would like to pursue that. Yes the plane should hold the shape of the path as it travels along the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by evaluating some points on the spline, add and subtract a normal vector to get vertices on both sides, and the compose a mesh out of those vertices using the polygon indices of a grid:

[image: Node Tree]

Then you replicate that mesh along a circle as follows:

[image: Node Tree]