# Recreate Curve Modifier in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'd like to "recreate" the curve modifier in animation nodes so that I can use it more procedurally. I know Omar showed how to do this with a basic plane in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126850/problem-with-curve-modifier-in-animation-nodes), but can anyone figure out how to expand his answer so that we could deform *any* mesh along *any* spline?

Looking at the [source code for the curve modifier](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_curve.c), it doesn't seem excessively complex.

I haven't worked out any of the internals, but here's what using such a node group might look like (input a mesh and a curve by which to deform it, then output the deformed mesh).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bend mesh along curve like this, Not same as curve modifier but you may get some idea.

[image]

[image]