# Cylinder Generator in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

What's a good way to make a procedural cylinder mesh in animation nodes? Usually I'd just use splines, but I need mesh geometry because I'd like to be able to use a displace modifier on the generated geometry. I've tried a couple different approaches myself but now I'm stumped. I'm imaging the node group setup would look something like this:

[image]

Parameter Explanations:

- START/END of the cylinder
- VERTICES: Number which controls the number of sides cylinder has
- RESOLUTION: Number of subdivisions/loops along the length of the cylinder

Answer (score 2):

you can use the node under "mesh->generator->cylinder".

With this node setup you can do all you want:

[image]

of course you can create a node group for this, but i think you know how to do that, if not, let me know.

Comment: I guess one downside of this is that there's no start/end parameter for the bottom/top of the cylinder. If anyone would like to share a custom setup that would allow you do this that could be helpful to people. For my purposes I'm just going to deform the  cylinder mesh via a spline (see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233413/recreate-curve-modifier-in-animation-nodes/233483#233483). Btw I don't know how to create this node group, creating meshes in AN has always been tricky for me!

Comment: One more note, seems like the built in cylinder mesh doesn't provide a means of adding additional rings to the length of the cylinder, just for setting the resolution of its curvature.